# How to create registry key of type REG_NONE?

Tags: windows, windows-registry, file-association

Information on files' associations are stored in `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Classes` and `HKCU\SOFTWARE\Classes` Windows' registry branches (among others). Each entry there can have `OpenWithProgIDs` key which adds programs named in it's values to the list of programs accessible from *Open With* entry in the context menu. Many of these keys have `REG_NONE` type. However *regedit* doesn't allow to create keys of this type - this type is absent from the list of key types available under *New* entry of the context menu.

How can I create a registry key of type `REG_NONE` to add new program to the list or to recreate previously deleted key?

Comment: You can do so with the Registry.SetValue method in .net: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3dwk5axy.aspx  Explanation of types here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.registryvaluekind.aspx

Comment: It might be best if you explain how you need to create the key or why, this question is likely to be closed as not constructive because it does not pose a question to a problem and does not specify any conditions or anything you have tried already. It is difficult to give an answer when no real question has been asked.

Comment: As @MaQleodmentioned, please be specific in your question and add some more details. Flag for reopening once done

Comment: I'm not sure why anyone would think this question isn't specific enough.  And there are many good questions on Super User that don't deal with a user's specific problem, they just ask a question.  Some have even been highlighted as top questions. Like [this one](http://superuser.com/questions/185980/what-is-the-origin-of-the-hard-drive-light).

Comment: @Lance This is apples and oranges. I agree to reopen though.

Answer (score 14):

I also needed to create a REG_NONE key in HKCR.

Using regedit I found an existing file association within HKCR that had a `REG_NONE` key under its OpenWithProgIDs branch (e.g. `HKCR\.mp3\OpenWithProgIDs`). I exported this registry to a `.reg` file.

Then, I used notepad to edit the exported file and changed the branch to match the location where I wanted the `REG_NONE` key. I deleted all the other keys listed except the one REG_NONE key I wanted. If you need to rename the REG_NONE key do that as well.

Import the file back into your registry and it will add the new key value as `REG_NONE`.

The `.reg` file looks like:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\..etc..\keyname]
@=hex(0):
```

Change `..etc..\keyname` to the actual key name. `@=hex(0):` is the line which creates the `REG_NONE` element.

Answer (score 0):

I needed to do something similar, in order to apply a particular file association to a different extension.

Creating a new Binary value (zero-length) with the appropriate name worked; I didn't actually need it to be REG_NONE.