# What does this light shaped like a cylinder mean?

Tags: laptop, led, indicator

I bought this Asus K53E laptop two years ago but I don't even know what this light means.

I'm referring to the middle one in the image below, between the battery and wireless lights.

[image]

Comment: I'm surprised you didn't find an answer in your laptop's user manual. You did check your user manual, didn't you ?

Comment: @pleinolijf I bought this laptop 2 year ago, I don't have the manual anymore.

Comment: Identification and image lookups are off topic

Comment: Per [this Meta post](https://meta.superuser.com/q/6073), identification questions are generally off-topic. Furthermore, this question shows a general lack of research effort; although not a close reason in and of itself, we expect all questions to show that the author has taken at least a minimal amount of effort in understanding and researching the question. However, since this question is relevant to a large audience, I've posted [a new Meta question](https://meta.superuser.com/q/13114) to have this closure reevaluated.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It represents your laptop's hard drive.  Whenever your hard disk is being accessed (reading or writing), the LED will light up.

The cylindrical shape is the universally accepted icon used to represent the hard disk.
For background information, there is a good [question](https://superuser.com/questions/185980/what-is-the-origin-of-the-hard-drive-light?rq=1) on SU already.

Comment: the question's on this site i.e. [su] not [so].

Comment: True, I meant the Stack Exchange network (of sites). I'll edit my answer.