# Is it possible to upgrade my Dell Inspiron 3421 processor?

Tags: cpu, motherboard

I have [Dell Inspiron 3421 Touch](http://www.dell.com/al/p/inspiron-14-3421/pd) laptop. I'm planning to upgrade my PC for performance. (because it is performing poorly with heavy development softwares)

I'm planning to buy [this i7 processor](http://ark.intel.com/products/80806/Intel-Core-i7-4790-Processor-8M-Cache-up-to-4_00-GHz). Will it be compatible with my hardware?
What factors matter while changing processor? What should I need to verify to check compatibility?

My current configuration is,

- Windows 8.1 64 bit
- Intel core i3-3217U CPU @ 1.80 GHz
- 4GB RAM
- Intel HD Graphics 4000
- Motherboard: Dell Inc. 0RDCXP (SOCKET 0)

Also suggest me RAM as I will upgrade that too.

Comment: You linked to a desktop product.  Its not possible to put a laptop CPU into a laptop that currently uses a mobile product.  Furthermore your processor is currently soldered to your motherboard.

Comment: How can I get similar processor for laptop then?

Comment: *You don't*.  Your processor isn't upgradable.  Its currently soldered to the motherboard.

Comment: So no way other than changing the whole laptop?

Comment: I assume you don't have soldering skills to remove a processor with 1023 solder joints and the equipment in order to do so.  You will be unable to upgrade your CPU in your laptop.

Comment: You are better off not deleting your question.

Comment: Are you sure the system is compute-bound? Upgrading to a solid-state drive may be a viable option and will more likely than not substantially improve performance. You'll be surprised how many workloads are in fact I/O bound...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### The processor is not upgradeable—consider installing an SSD instead.

- Your laptop uses a soldered (BGA 1023) processor, which cannot be replaced without special equipment.
- You should consider installing a **[solid-state drive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solid-state_drive)** instead. The vast majority of consumer workloads are **not** compute-bound, but are I/O bound due to the slow random I/O performance of mechanical hard drives. Replacing the hard drive with an SSD will more likely than not significantly improve overall system performance.
- If your system's disk activity light ([indicated by a cylinder](https://superuser.com/questions/515115/what-does-this-light-shaped-like-a-cylinder-mean)) is constantly lit while the system is busy, than the system is I/O bound and will benefit from an SSD.

Comment: Suggest me some compatible SSD that can address my issue. What to keep in mind while buying it?

Comment: You might want to look at the Samsung SSD 850 EVO.